# IOS allocation problems with MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: memory-management, ios-simulator, instruments, static-memory-allocation

in my ipad app in viewDidLoad i set up a video in the first view so to have an intro.
In allocation tool i see that allocated memory grow till 120MB when running the video, ok i dont care, but after the video finish i would like that memory to go to 0 again BUT stick to 120MB, what am i doing wrong ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                 pathForResource:@"sfed" 
                 ofType:@"mp4"];

playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
 initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:[playerViewController moviePlayer]];





[videoview addSubview:playerViewController.view];


MPMoviePlayerController *player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024, 748, 0, 0);
[player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

[player play];
}





- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
 MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];
 [player stop];
 [player release];  




[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

[videoview setAlpha:0];

[UIView commitAnimations];
[videoview release];
```

}

Comment: What does this have to do with Xcode?

Comment: IOS sdk ? if you see Xcode and MPMoviePlayerViewController what do you think ?

Comment: If I see Xcode I assume you are having some issue with the IDE. Use iOS tag if you mean iOS.

Comment: edited, anyway i think better thing is answer the question, if you can understand its, not blame for title settings! THANKS